# Prisma circumvent a certain model

Tags: prisma

I encountered a challenge while attempting to create a Prisma query. Specifically, I am working on retrieving all subcategories within a certain category and endeavoring to circumvent the product type model to access all products. My goal is to then order these products based on the number of orders they have received.

```
model Category {
    id   Int    @id @default(autoincrement()) @db.TinyInt
    name String @unique @db.VarChar(50)

    subCategories Subcategory[]
}

model Subcategory {
    id   Int    @id @default(autoincrement()) @db.TinyInt
    name String @unique @db.VarChar(50)

    category   Category @relation(fields: [categoryId], references: [id])
    categoryId Int      @db.TinyInt

    productTypes ProductType[]

    @@index([categoryId])
}

model ProductType {
    id   Int    @id @default(autoincrement()) @db.TinyInt
    name String @unique @db.VarChar(50)

    subcategory   Subcategory @relation(fields: [subcategoryId], references: [id])
    subcategoryId Int         @db.TinyInt

    products Product[]

    @@index([subcategoryId])
}

model Product {
    id                      Int         @id @default(autoincrement())
    name                    String      @db.VarChar(255)
    productType             ProductType @relation(fields: [productTypeId], references: [id])
    productTypeId           Int         @db.TinyInt

    personType PersonType

    orderOnProduct OrderOnProduct[]

    @@index([productTypeId])
}
```

I initially attempted the standard 'include' approach, but it didn't yield the desired results as it didn't allow me to order the products by the number of orders across all product types in a certain subcategory.